# How to bind event Jquery to page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Jquery function that executes AJAX query to server.
How can I call this after load page in the specified url page? May I bind this to element HTML, I mean:

```
<div id="graph" onload="function()"></div>
```

Comment: Yuk... Rather put this into an external file `$(window).load(function () { callMe(); });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery handles the HTML file with a variable called `document`.

Document has two popular event states

1. `load` when the page has been loaded
2. `ready` when the page has been loaded and all other decorations to the HTML have been applied.

jQuery provides hooks for these states.

To run javascript code after each of the events listed above, you have to put the function within the appropriate *event scope*.

For loading, this would be…

```
$(document).load(function() {
  // javascript code you want to execute
})
```

After the page has been ready, but not yet rendered, you can apply some other javascript code using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // javascript code you want to execute
})
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 //do whatever you need, you can check if some element exists and then, call your function
  if($("#graph").length > 0)
    callfunction();
});
```

No jQuery, only vanilla js:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(document.getElementById("graph"))
       callfunction();
}
```

Comment: Okay, but how can I pass param to this function from PHP?

Comment: I thinks this is other issue @MisterPi not related to the original question.

Comment: There are multiple ways. You can use data attriobutes from html: https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/ store the values in data-* attributes and then retrieve then inside your function.